# Where to set the System Properties in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am exploring the [EC2 plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin) of Jenkins. One of the issues reported is with the Authentication Timeout.

```
jenkins.ec2.bootstrapAuthSleepMs (default 30000)
jenkins.ec2.bootstrapAuthTries (default 30)
```

I am seeing this issue with my install and I am trying to set the properties accordingly. So far without any success. Where do you increase the default timeout values for a jenkins install as suggested on the Install page?

Answer (score 8):

These are regular JVM system properties. Pass them using -Denkins.ec2.bootstrapAuthSleepMs=value and -Djenkins.ec2.bootstrapAuthTries=value on Jenkins startup. You need to edit the Jenkins configuration/startup script on disk and restart Jenkins to apply the changes.

In most Jenkins installations, this is the "JAVA_ARGS" variable in the Jenkins config or startup script. On ubuntu/debian, this is configured in /etc/default/jenkins.

Comment: In Jenkins 2.7.1 on CentOS the file is /etc/sysconfig/jenkins and the variable is JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS

Comment: I don't find sysconfig under /etc in Ubuntu 16.04, where does this exists ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution that worked for me on:

> Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11)
> x86_64 GNU/Linux

1. open file **/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/jenkins.service**
2. modify value for key "Environment" for your desires
3. # systemctl daemon-reload
4. # service jenkins restart

now call

> # ps aux | grep -i jenkins

to see, if it worked.